# Firestore rules when data doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a rule that only lets a user create/edit a document in which `request.auth.uid` matches the name of the document they're trying to create. From https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/secure-data:

> Using variables from wildcards
>
> When you match a rule using a database path with a wildcard, a 
>   variable is created with a name matching the string you included 
>   inside the curly brackets. You can then reference these variables in 
>   your security rules.
>
> One common use of these types of wildcards is to store documents by 
>   userID, and then only allow users to access documents for which their 
>   userID matches the ID of the document.
>
> ```
> service cloud.firestore {
>   match /databases/{database}/documents {
>     match /users/{userIDFromWildcard}/ {
>       // Users can only edit documents in the database if the documentID is
>       // equal to their userID
>       allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userIDFromWildcard;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

I tried using this code in my rules, but it errors. When removing the last `/`, i.e. `match /users/{userIDFromWildcard}` instead of `match /users/{userIDFromWildcard}/`, it publishes, but permissions aren't granted if the document doesn't exist.

Edit: I also tried something like this, but I don't know how to do it correctly because of the lack of documentation:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.__name__;
```

This is the code I'm running that gets `insufficient permissions`:

```
this.items = afs.doc("/users/" + this.uid); // afs is AngularFirestore, this.uid is the uid of the authenticated user
```

...

```
// the user is authenticated at this point
this.items.snapshotChanges().subscribe(snapshot => {
if (!snapshot.payload.exists) { // if user isn't in db
    function recursive() {
        // ...
        this.updateDB(); // called once because of conditional
    }
    recursive();
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

`updateDB`:

```
public updateDatabase(): void {
    const changes: Item = { name: this.name, username: this.username, 
    photoURL: this.photoURL };
    this.items.set(changes).then((item) => { // causes error
        console.log("Saving successful");
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're running that produces the error and what the error looks like?

Comment: @hatboysam There's no error, it simply isn't working. Unfortunately, firestore rules don't have a simulator or decent debugging tools. The code is in the question, a direct copy/paste of the code in the quote except without the last slash

Comment: those are only your rules, what about the code that actually calls `set()` or `update()` to write the data?  And that's the code that should produce some error.

Comment: @hatboysam Oh yes, my question is not detailed enough. It will be updated shortly

Answer (score 1):

You probably need this setup for documents:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /database/{databases}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, if you need to write to a sub-collections see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47313055/4056031)

And more info on wildcard matching in firestore [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data#recursive_matching_with_wildcards)